# send login credential to plink serial session with script

Tags: python, powershell

i am using visual studio code environment.
I am getting stuck while using,
plink -serial $comport in my powershell script.
by this i am able to getting in to that my virtual machine but after that i want to give login credential to that plink session
is there any way to give login credential to plink session???

in python script i call my powershell script by using subprocess.
in that powershell script i used plink -serial $comport.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", 
          "C:\\Users\\Documents\\12_april.ps1"], 
          stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
```

after running this script i am able to get login screen but after that how to give login credential with help of script to that plink session that i am not getting.